# How to extract first "word" after bracket

Tags: regex, r

Sorry for asking that kind of question, but I can't find a way and I has been working on this last 2 hours. So I was able to create pattern for bracket and name which is `\\) \\w\\.\\w+","//1` but I can't find a way to write a pattern just for a name and how to extract this name from the string and assign to variable.

here is example of string

```
"(7:54) (Shotgun) B.Hoyer sacked at JAC 49 for -7 yards (R.Miller). FUMBLES (R.Miller), recovered by HOU-X.Su'a-Filo at JAC 50. X.Su'a-Filo to JAC 42 for 8 yards (T.Alualu; A.Branch)."
```

and here is expected result

```
B.Hoyer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to re-escape this i.e. re-add double slashes where required, but would something like this work?

```
^\(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\)\s\(.*\)\s(.*?)\s.*$
```

They key lay in the `(.*?)\s` which is any number of characters up to the space, lazily i.e. the matching group will terminate at the first space.

**EDIT:** See Dawg's note below explaining that `^(?:[^)]*\)){2}\s*([\w.]+)` is substantially more efficient...

Comment: While this works, it is more complicated (and involves more backtracking) than necessary. `^(?:[^)]*\)){2}\s*([\w.]+)` is 13 steps to a match. `^\(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\)\s\(.*\)\s(.*?)\s.*$` is over 200 steps for the same match.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
^(?:[^)]*\)){2}\s*([\w.]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW6mB0/1)